# Rounded DataGrid Corners?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to apply some styles to a Datagrid, but I am getting an error. 
I am trying to apply rounded corners to a `DataGrid`.

This is the error I am getting on , `<Setter.Value>`

> The attachable property 'Value' was not found in type 'Setter'

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
     <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0" />
     <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
         <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                    <Grid>
                 　　  <Border CornerRadius="5"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
</Style>
```

I found this question [Datagrid template with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120205/datagrid-template-with-rounded-corners), but it does help with my question.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you'll be Ok.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                   <Border Background="Red" CornerRadius="5">
                   </Border>
               </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
</Style>
```

You actually didn't specify the name of the property for the `Setter.Value`. The

```
<Setter.Value></Setter.Value>
```

must be enclosed inside a

```
<Setter Property="NameOfthePropertyToSetTheValueFor"></Setter>
```

For the case of `CornerRadius` the property must be `Template`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a

> < Setter Property="Template">

2 lines above the ControlTemplate declaration

*remove space before 'Setter':)

Answer (score 1):

The indents are sort of helping you in the issue.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
     <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0" />
     <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
     <Setter Property="ControlTemplate">
         <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                    <Grid>
                 　　  <Border CornerRadius="5"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```